# Add Global Menu to MATE 1.8.1 (ubuntuMATE)

Tags: 14.04, indicator, mate, globalmenu

I just installed ubuntuMATE 14.04; honestly, I love it.
However, I'm missing the global menu from Unity and older mate distros.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get Indicator Applet Appmenu working or install a different gm applet?
Many thanks to whoever has an answer, I just spent the last five hours sifting through PPAs and good ol' google trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [TopMenu](https://gitorious.org/topmenu/pages/Home), a global menu bar applet for MATE 1.8+.
You can find precompiled packages and instructions in [Web Upd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/12/get-global-menu-in-mate-18-with-topmenu.html).

Comment: Very close. I'm glad to see that somebody finally made something.
However, it wasn't quite what I was looking for. Hopefully they will be able to make it more compatible with other applications at a later date.